# Word like vegan applicable to onine privacy

Tags: word-request

I'm looking for a word with a similar meaning as "vegan" in the context of online privacy.
Just like a "vegan product" and a "vegan individual":

1. I'm a `[privacy vegan]` and try to avoid data mining websites.
2. Our website is `[privacy vegan]`. We don't track your activity.

**Edit / clarification**

A vegan person refrains from eating animal products. A producer can label its products "vegan" for marketing purposes. If I want to market a digital product with the absence of trackers, what word do I use that both is identifiable to persons and makes sense as a marketing term. (Like vegan does)

Comment: What exactly do you think "vegan" means / implies, and how does that relate to issues like data privacy?

Comment: A vegan person refrains from eating animal products. A producer can label its products "vegan" for marketing. If I want to market a digital product with the absence of trackers, what word do I use that both is identifiable to persons and makes sense as a marketing term.

Comment: Anglophones in general would not make a connection between a person refraining from eating animal products and a software product "refraining" from tracking web-based users, so the question as posed here isn't really meaningful.

Comment: ...a few people have adopted the collocation [***privacy evangelists***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22privacy+evangelists%22&oq=%22privacy+evangelists%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.7327j1j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), which probably has the connotations you seek.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think you’ll find a single word for this.

As for the personal example, something like the following comes to mind:

> As a strong **proponent** of personal privacy, I...

For a website, you’d usually hear something simple, definitive and unequivocal, such as:

> We value your privacy, and (will) never track your activity.

If you include the word ‘will’, you should be certain you’re going to stick to this principle in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I get what you're trying to do, but your analogy is strange. Although vegans themselves prefer to be known for having a plant-based diet, the fact is most people view it as a diet of *exclusion*, so making a pun on veganism might make people think you *reject* privacy like a vegan rejects meat, when in fact you're trying to *promote* it (privacy, not meat!)

Some ways to say you are *pro-privacy* might be:

- Privacy addict
- Privacy aficionado
- Privacy buff
- Privacy devotee
- Privacy fan
- Privacy fanatic
- Privacy lover
- Privacy supporter
- Privacy zealot

Because those terms apply to *people*, they don't really work for a website. You could just say your website is **pro-privacy**, or maybe **privacy friendly**?